# UE4 Casting OtherActor on OnComponentBeginOverlap

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Am new at UE4. Now i am colliding two classes. a pawn and a character class. My OnComponentBeginOverlap dynamic is in pawn class. That means i am trying to get OtherActor from my pawn class. OtherActor should be a ACharacter class. Now let's see the parameter signature:

```
void Adenn_pawn::OnOverlapBegin(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComp, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool FromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
```

Look at the second parameter. it defines AActor class but i dont want access it's parent classes. I can use the AActor functions or properties. Actually i want to use ACharacter because it is a ACharacter Class. Any ideas about casting this "OtherActor" as its own class. Or how can i change to a subclass?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Cast<ACharacter>(OtherActor)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try casting `OtherActor` to a variable of type `ACharacter*` using the `Cast` function. Luckily the function will check if the actor overlapped is of type `ACharacter`, so this is helpful when you're not sure if `OtherActor` is of type `ACharacter`. You can call the `Cast` function and do what you wish with the casted actor like so,

```
if (ACharacter* OtherCharacter = Cast<ACharacter>(OtherActor))
{
    // do stuff with OtherCharacter
}
else
{
    // OtherActor does not point to an object of type ACharacter
}
```